# Solving a polynomial via NSolve

Tags: equation-solving

I have been trying to solve the following equation via `NSolve`:

```
func[a_,n_]:=M(r^6-n^6+15n^4*r^2-15n^2*r^4)-2M^2r(3r^4-2n^2r^2+3n^4)-16n^4r^3+8ar^(3/2)(M(r^2-n^2)+2n^2r)^(3/2)+a^2(M(n^4+6n^2r^2-3r^4)-8n^2r^3)
```

I want to find `r` in terms of `M` for different values of `a` and `n`. Now, I can solve a scenario where one of `a` or `n` is zero. For example, if I do

```
NSolve[Thread[func[0.9M,0]==0],r]
```

I can find a solution but I could not find `r` in a case where

```
NSolve[Thread[func[1.2M,1M]==0],r]
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: `NSolve` solves numeric systems. This is one equation in two variables, hence has a (non-numeric) parameter. Not something `NSolve` can handle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remember that when you write something like `ar` with no space between, it is treated as a variable named `ar` instead of `a*r`. So let's add a space there:

```
func[a_,n_]:=M(r^6-n^6+15n^4r^2-15n^2r^4)-2M^2r(3r^4-
2n^2r^2+3n^4)-16n^4r^3+8a r^(3/2)(M(r^2-n^2)+2n^2r)^(3/2)+
a^2(M(n^4+6n^2r^2-3r^4)-8n^2r^3).
```

Also, it's generally a bad idea to use capital letters for variable names; many (Like `N`, `C`, etc.) are reserved for special purposes in mma. I would recommend using a different name for `M`.

Let's define the equation you want to solve, and let's use exact numbers like 12/10 instead of 1.2:

```
forSolve = func[12 M/10, 1 M]
(*-16 M^4 r^3 - 2 M^2 r (3 M^4 - 2 M^2 r^2 + 3 r^4) + 
 M (-M^6 + 15 M^4 r^2 - 15 M^2 r^4 + r^6) + 
 48/5 M r^(3/2) (2 M^2 r + M (-M^2 + r^2))^(3/2) + 
 36/25 M^2 (-8 M^2 r^3 + M (M^4 + 6 M^2 r^2 - 3 r^4)) *)
```

Note that there is a symbolic parameter `M` in `forSolve`, so we should not use `NSolve` which is a numerical method, and instead use `Solve`:

```
solns = Solve[forSolve==0, r];
```

This generates a set of `Root` objects that cannot be reduced `ToRadicals`. We can however get numerical approximations of the roots:

```
solns // N
(*{{r -> 3.61787 M}, {r -> 11.4344 M}, {r -> (-2.07662 - 1.24017 I) M},...{}}*)
```

There is also the warning message generated by `Solve`:

`Solve::nongen: There may be values of the parameters for which some or all solutions are not valid.`

Indeed, as the warning message hints at, some of the roots are not close to 0 when we plug them into the function with `M=1` for example:

```
atRoot = forSolve /. solns;
N[atRoot /. M -> 1] // Chop
(*{0, 1.39961*10^6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.215596 + 0.262061 I, 
 0.215596 - 0.262061 I, -0.213027 + 0.18311 I, -0.213027 - 
  0.18311 I, 0, 0}}*)
```

So when using `Solve` on this specific function, it's important to validate the roots by plugging them into the function.

Restricting `Solve` to only look for roots in the `Reals` yields one (hopefully valid) root (with the condition that M>0). I test it here for some values between M=0.1 and 2 and the values all appear to be generally close to 0:

```
realSolns = Solve[forSolve == 0, r, Reals];
atRealRoot = forSolve /. realSolns;
N[Table[atRealRoot /. M -> i, {i, 1/10, 2, 1/10}], 16] // Chop
(* {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, \
{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}*)
```

Looking at this real root with high precision, we see it probably is a good candidate root for all values of `M>0`:

```
N[Simplify[forSolve /. (realSolns // ToRadicals), M > 0], 128]
(*{0.*10^-174 M^7}*)
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much.